# Run globally installed node module from electron app

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, vue-devtools

I am trying to startup [`vue-devtools`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/blob/dev/packages/shell-electron/README.md) from within my app but I am getting an error:

> Uncaught Exception:
>   Error: spawn vue-devtools ENOENT
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>       at onErrorNT
>       at processTicksAndRections

I am using the following which is giving me this error:

```
app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
    let devtools = cp.spawn('vue-devtools')
  }
  createWindow()
})
```

I installed devtools globally using

```
npm i -g @vue/devtools
```

So, when I run I would expect the program to run. What is causing it to not execute?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was quite simple. I just needed to pass `shell: true` to the options.

```
app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
    let devtools = cp.spawn('vue-devtools', {
      cwd: __dirname,
      shell: true,
      windowsHide: true
    })
  }
  createWindow()
})
```